# Can Power Query prompt for a file name when loading a text file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, import, power-query

Power Query can be used to pull text files into Excel.

But does it
have an equivalent to Excel's External Data's "Prompt for file name on refresh"?

That is, to assume the pulled text file has a dynamic name and therefore ask to browse for it each time a refresh is triggered.

I know Power Query has a feature of Parameters, but can they trigger a "choose file" prompt?

[image: Excel's From Text's prompt for a file name on refresh]

Comment: Probably not possible through PQ alone, but VBA/Macros might achieve this. I don't know how exactly.

Comment: If so, what a big limitation compared to the simple UI of External Data. Do you have a VBA to prompt then interact with Power Query?